# PHP Included Array Warning

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, environment

I'm having a problem with an array in php, which I use to store configuration data for different environments. The idea is that I only have to switch out the file with the config data when going from local testing to using it on the server. The file looks like this:

```
<?php
  $_ENV = array(
    'MySQL' => array(
      'database'=>'<DATABASENAME>',
      'server'=>'<SERVERNAME>',
      'username'=>'<USERNAME>',
      'password'=>'<PASSWORD>'
    )
  );
?>
```

And I include it this way:

```
include('../env.php');
```

For the connection to the database I use it like this:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($_ENV['MySQL']['server'], $_ENV['MySQL']['username'],$_ENV['MySQL']['password']) or die("No connection possible: " . mysql_error());
```

Ignoring the fact that I'm still using mysql instead of PDO or mysqli, which is a thing I'm going to change soon, this should work. But it does not:

```
Notice: Undefined index: MySQL in D:\data\dev\applications\wtc-feedback\dashboard\include\SQLrequest.php on line 36
```

The strange thing is that when I dump the environment variable onto the screen with var_dump() the indexes and the contents are all just fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: To make sure the code is actually included, you should first change `include` to `require`. Is perhaps the same include loaded from a different include / script during the same request?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the array? You should never make changes to the $_ENV array, and maybe it is prohibited by your php version

Comment: The code you've shared should work fine. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Blaatpraat Superglobals have never been read-only.

Comment: in fact it works normal in my local php version (5.6)

Comment: The strange thing is that I'm using the exact same construct on another Project and there it works just fine. Changing the variable name or include to require did not do anything

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Doesn't change the case that OP should never make changes to $_ENV.

Comment: @Blaatpraat If you think it's bad practice just say so, there's no need to support it with "alternative facts" ;-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález What "alternative facts" did I give? On the official php docs it is mentioned that you should never make changes to $_ENV, so there was a change that the devs made it impossible to alter the array directly. Hence the word "maybe", that means that I'm not sure of that.

Comment: @Blaatpraat, out of curiosity, could you point where in the official docs it says that? Or where did you see about `$_ENV` being readonly? I'm trying to find it without success. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If You want to work with environmental variables use [getenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php), [putenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php)

or use `.env` files (package [here](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/dotenv), docs [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-dotenv-component)) and add `.env` to `.gitignore`

in fact Your code must be like this:

env.php:

```
<?php

putenv('DB_NAME=DATABASENAME');
putenv('DB_HOST=SERVERNAME');
putenv('DB_USER=USERNAME');
putenv('DB_PASS=PASSWORD');
```

connection.php:

```
<?php

include('../env.php');
$conn = mysql_connect(getenv('DB_HOST'), getenv('DB_USER'), getenv('DB_PASS')) 
        OR die("No connection possible: " . mysql_error());
```

".env" way:

.env file:

```
DB_NAME=DATABASENAME
DB_HOST=SERVERNAME
DB_USER=USERNAME
DB_PASS=PASSWORD
```

connection.php:

```
<?php

require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
(new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');

$conn = mysql_connect(getenv('DB_HOST'), getenv('DB_USER'), getenv('DB_PASS')) 
        OR die("No connection possible: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer and now cannot un-downvote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: I tried it that way yet getenv('DB_NAME') seems to be empty.

Comment: @Curunir,  could be because of `safe_mode_allowed_env_vars` settings.

Comment: @Curunir, it seems like yivi is right. Cuz even Your code in question works as expected in my local computer.

Comment: @yivi btw safe_mode is removed after 5.4 (: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php

Comment: yup, was aware of that. but OP didn't specify which PHP were they running. :)

Comment: Hope will figure out (:

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution wouuld be, return the simple array from the file. as

```
<?php
 return array(
'MySQL' => array(
  'database'=>'<DATABASENAME>',
  'server'=>'<SERVERNAME>',
  'username'=>'<USERNAME>',
  'password'=>'<PASSWORD>'
 )
);
?>
```

In other file

```
$credentials = require_once "../env.php";
```

Use the `$credentials` array to supply parameters to mysql connection function

Comment: BTW in the proposed solution, there is no issue. I use it. although it does not implement env methods. ;-)